# Polymer specific styling to conditional templates

Tags: polymer

I've got a question related to styling in Polymer. I have a responsive element which has different stylings depending on the width of the screen. If the width is 720 or greater, it should have the styling that is marked with "--specific styling 2--". If it isn't, it should have the "--specific styling 2--". It should always have the "--common styling--".

```
<dom-module>
<template>
    <style>
      :host {
        --common styling--
      }
    </style>

    <iron-media-query query="min-width: 720px" query-matches="{{isWide}}"></iron-media-query>

    <template is="dom-if" if="{{!isWide}}">
      <style>
        :host {
          --specific styling 1--
        }
      </style>      
    </template>

    <template is="dom-if" if="{{isWide}}">
      <style>
        :host {
          --specific styling 2--
        }
      </style>      
    </template>
</template>
</dom-module>
```

If I have the code as above, it always uses the "--specific styling 2--". Is there some way to change this to the wanted behaviour?

Bart

Comment: Have you tried using normal css media queries? Or is there a reason why you're not using them?

Comment: It's not possible to use them in polymer. However someone from the polymer team helped me. Here is more information:

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2627